# how works setTimeout inside a for loop? - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, settimeout

Why this

```js
for(x = 0; x < 10; x++){
  
  var delay = x;
  
  setTimeout(
    function(){
     $('body').append(delay);
    }, delay)
  
}
```

Returns this: `9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9`

instead of this : `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

[http://jsfiddle.net/c1hotu9a/](http://jsfiddle.net/c1hotu9a/1/)

Comment: The loop doesn't wait for the timeouts to trigger.

Comment: How can i get the second output?

Comment: I would not call it duplicate however your ans is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop